# sort an array with created_at data on rails (with sort_by { |x| x.created_at } it just keep it the same way

Tags: mysql, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

I got this code:

```
def user_activity
      @array_activity = []
      @testannounces = Announce.all
      @testchallenges = Challenge.all
      @testannounces.each do |x|
        @array_temp = []
        @array_temp.push x.created_at
        @array_temp.push "annonunce"
        @array_temp.push x
        @array_activity.push @array_temp
      end
      @testchallenges.each do |y|
        @array_temp = []
        @array_temp.push y.created_at
        @array_temp.push "challenge"
        @array_temp.push y
        @array_activity.push @array_temp
      end
      @array_activity.sort_by { |x| x[2].created_at }
end
```

well, by printing only that x[2].created_at, it returns me this

```
<% @array_activity.each do |x| %>
  <p><%= x[2].created_at %></p>
<% end %>
```

2015-03-18 22:52:48 UTC

2015-03-18 22:59:06 UTC

2015-03-19 16:42:41 UTC

2015-03-19 23:20:25 UTC

2015-03-20 15:46:17 UTC

2015-03-23 23:35:43 UTC

2015-03-23 23:37:52 UTC

2015-03-23 23:59:37 UTC

2015-03-23 20:34:43 UTC

(I got just 1 item on challenges, and if u can notice, it's 2015-03-23 20:34:43 wish is early than 2015-03-23 23:59:37 UTC)

Somebody know what could be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sort_by` does not mutate the receiver. If you want to use the return value, save it to a variable.

```
@activity_array = @array_activity.sort_by { |x| x[2].created_at }
```

Alternatively, you could use the bang version to modify the receiver.

```
@array_activity.sort_by! { |x| x[2].created_at }
```